expo react-native-iap E_IAP_NOT_AVAILABLE
Hello I am am trying to utilize react-native-iap in my react-native expo app and no matter what I try I am getting the error "E_IAP_NOT_AVAILABLE" which after doing some digging is being cause by StokeKit not being available (1 or 2). I added react-native-iap to my plugins in app.json. What other setup step am I missing. I have tried through both expo go (i hear it wont work there but I tried) and by exporting to testflight and then trying from there. I don't know what else to try. Below I have added my packages and the bulk of my code that tries to setup iap and causes the error.
Edit: I created a snack showing the error (not sure if react-native-iap would even work in a snack, but just trying to be helpful):
https://snack.expo.dev/@tristan-neateworks/expo-react-native-iap-e_iap_not_available
Packages:
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.5.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@shopify/react-native-skia": "1.2.3",
    "expo-asset": "~10.0.8",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-image": "~1.12.11",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.16",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.4.10",
    "react-native-iap": "^12.13.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.16",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "*"
  },

iap setup
import React from "react-native";
import {View} from "react-native";
import {
    withIAPContext, setup,
    initConnection,
    purchaseErrorListener,
    purchaseUpdatedListener,
    flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid, finishTransaction,
} from 'react-native-iap';
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {api, getUser} from "../../be";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

function Listener({children}) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    let purchaseUpdateSubscription = null;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    let purchaseErrorSubscription = null;
    useEffect(() => {
        void (async () => {

            console.log('t2')
            await initConnection().then(() => {
                // we make sure that "ghost" pending payment are removed
                // (ghost = failed pending payment that are still marked as pending in Google's native Vending module cache)
                console.log('t3')
                flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid()
                    .catch(() => {
                        console.log('t4')
                        // exception can happen here if:
                        // - there are pending purchases that are still pending (we can't consume a pending purchase)
                        // in any case, you might not want to do anything special with the error
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('t5')
                        purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(
                            (purchase) => {
                                console.log('purchaseUpdatedListener', purchase);
                                const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
                                if (receipt) {
                                    console.log(receipt)
                                    api('iap/receipt/', 'POST', purchase.transactionReceipt)
                                        .then(async (deliveryResult) => {
                                            if (deliveryResult.success === true) {
                                                // Tell the store that you have delivered what has been paid for.
                                                // Failure to do this will result in the purchase being refunded on Android and
                                                // the purchase event will reappear on every relaunch of the app until you succeed
                                                // in doing the below. It will also be impossible for the user to purchase consumables
                                                // again until you do this.

                                                // If consumable (can be purchased again)
                                                // await finishTransaction({purchase, isConsumable: true});
                                                // If not consumable
                                                await finishTransaction({purchase, isConsumable: false});
                                                // mark subscription as active
                                            } else {
                                                // Retry / conclude the purchase is fraudulent, etc...
                                            }
                                        });
                                }
                            },
                        );

                        purchaseErrorSubscription = purchaseErrorListener(
                            (error) => {
                                console.log('t6')
                                console.warn('purchaseErrorListener', error);
                            },
                        );
                    });
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log('t10')
                console.log(e)
                // exception can happen here if:
                // - there are pending purchases that are still pending (we can't consume a pending purchase)
                // in any case, you might not want to do anything special with the error
            });
        })()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log('t7')
            // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
            if (purchaseUpdateSubscription) {
                purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
                purchaseUpdateSubscription = null;
            }

            if (purchaseErrorSubscription) {
                purchaseErrorSubscription.remove();
                purchaseErrorSubscription = null;
            }
            console.log('t7.5')
        }
    }, [])
    return <View>{children}</View>
}

console.log('t1')
setup({storekitMode: 'STOREKIT2_MODE'})
export default withIAPContext(Listener)


Delete the ios folder, then npx expo run:ios

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
